# How can I mentioned a Chapter and its subsections in the same sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, parallelism

I would like to introduce my chapter and its subsections a sentence. Here is my try:

> Chapter (1) contains three main parts. First part, namely Section (1.1), establishes method A. Second part of this chapter, in Section (1.2), we develop a novel estimation method.

I feel that my sentence is correct, but the structure is not. 
How can I press my idea in a clear nice way? any help, please?

Comment: You don't have to put them in one sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Chapter (1) contains three main parts: Section (1.1) establishes method A, and in Section (1.2), we develop a novel estimation method.

There you go. Is section 3 joining this party? (It doesn't have to, but it should follow shortly if you're going to mention it in this sentence.)